# How to make a Windows desktop shortcut (with shortcut key) to open a Chrome pop-up window

Tags: windows, google-chrome, shell, file-shortcut

If you create a desktop shortcut, and set a shortcut key in its properties, you can use that shortcut key in any application.

How can  you make such a shortcut so it opens a Chrome **pop-up** window, not a full Chrome window.

Since I generally have an instance of Chrome running, I now use a shortcut to chrome.exe with command line parameters `--` and the path to a local HTML file that has this:

```
<script>if(window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm','NewMail '+(new Date()).toString(),'width=650,height=800,left=1200,top=50'))window.close();</script>
```

It will open a new tab, and first deny the pop-up. If you allow that, it works. (After a Chrome update, the first such pop-up is denied again though the setting is still there, but this is a separate issue with Chrome.) Also it loads a little slower than hitting shift-click on the compose button on the GMail tab, but it's fast enough for me, and for a moment a tab flashes and vanishes, but that doesn't btoher me.

The question is if there's a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here ya are:

32 Bit Windows 7+:

`C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe /new-window https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1`

64 Bit Windows 7+:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe /new-window https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1`

32/64 Bit XP:
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\Application /new-window https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1`

Comment: Nope. Not only is chrome.exe here in this machine in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\Application`, it opens a tab in the existing window or a new window, something I specifically do not want.

Comment: @StijnSanders I assumed Windows 7+ and it will open in a new window, but chrome defaults are to open in new tab to save RAM

Comment: This works for me on win10, thanks!   i did have to put the C:\Program...  in Quotes,  so this is what i used as a desktop shortcut (and added a hotkey to it,  all in native win10) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" /new-window https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&shva=1